# Auto-match criteria by location

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

How does Google match two players looking for a random game? For our app it is better to match people from the same location. Is Google already preferring people living closer together when matching them?

If not: Is there a better approach to match players than seperating the world by longitudes and latitudes, generating a unique id per square and use setVariant(id)?